# Angular2-5 Generic Directive to render different styles on html elements

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-directive

I am writing Angular5 application where I am animating objects on the basis of different top and left positions.

I have a parent div where I am animating 3 child div elements successfully.
**Problem:**
My code works for a fixed number of child divs but I need to make it work for any number of child divs.

My **animation.compoenent.ts** sets style like this

```
this.styles = { 'transform':'translate(0px,0px)', 'position': 'absolute', 'top': top+'px', 'left': left+'px' };

this.ballStyleChange = new  BehaviorSubject<any>(this.styles);
```

My **animation.component.html** looks like

```
<div class="parent-container">
     <div [ball1Style] = "ball1StyleChange">Child1</div>
     <div [ball2Style] = "ball2StyleChange">Child1</div>
     <div [ball3Style] = "ball3tyleChange">Child1</div>
</div>
```

I have written 3 directives to handle styling of these 3 different Child divs.
here is how one of my **ball1directive** looks like

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { PlayerStyle } from '../Models/PlayerStyle';
@Directive({ selector: '[ballStyle]' })
export class StyleDirective implements OnInit{
@Input() ballStyle: Observable<any>;  
constructor(public el: ElementRef,public renderer: Renderer) {
}
ngOnChanges()
{
    this.ballStyle.subscribe(
        result=>
        {               
            let style = "transform:"+result.transform+"; position: absolute; 
     top:"+ result.top+ "; left:"+result.left +";";
            this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'style', 
    style);               
        });
}
   ngOnInit(){      
   }
}


import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Directive({  selector: '[ball1Style]'})
export class Ball12Directive implements OnInit {  
@Input() ball1Style: Observable<any>;
constructor(public el: ElementRef,public renderer: Renderer) { }
ngOnInit() { }
   ngOnChanges()
   {        
        this.ball1Style.subscribe(
        result=>
        {
            let style = "transform:"+result.transform+"; position: absolute; top:"+ result.top+ "; left:"+result.left +";";
            this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'style', style);               
        });
    }
}
```

So these are two of my 3 directives, Now the thing is all of my child divs will be moving in different directions and I need to handle all with one directive so as to make it generic for any number of child divs.

Do share your thoughts, would be really helpful.
Thanks 
Sohaib

Comment: Can you provide the code for the other two? We need more details around how the other two are changing to provide assistance

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have updated code above. You can see directives are same

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it seems like your code should be able to be re-used for n number of objects by having the selector and input property be generic like `ballStyle` instead of `ball1Style`, `ball2Style`, etc. Your html would then consist of a bunch of these: `<div [ballStyle]="ball1StyleChange">Child1</div>`

Comment: Are you wanting a generic component that allows you to pass in any number of style properties to set, beyond the 4 that you are in the example above? I'm lost as to what you are asking for

Comment: I have list of points to loop through and I need to smoothly animate the balls. For proper animation effect I am using windows.requestAnimationFrame. to make it happen this way directive is the only thing I could find helpful.

Comment: If you need help to have your animation component work with any number of items to animate, you'll need to provide more details. Otherwise the directive you have is simply duplicating stuff provided by the Angular team and provided in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have here, I don't think that the directive is necessary as there already is one provided by the Angular team that does what you need. You should be able to use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) along with the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

```html
<div class="parent-container">
    <div [ngStyle]="ball1StyleChange | async">Child1</div>
    <div [ngStyle]="ball2StyleChange | async">Child2</div>
    <div [ngStyle]="ball3StyleChange | async">Child3</div>
</div>
```